# Intermittent error when running react-native ios simulator ("couldn't boot your defined simulator due to an already booted simulator")

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Running react native project on Sierra using xCode v9.1.

Full error:
`CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Frameworks/InstrumentsPackaging.framework/Versions/A/Resources/XRPackageModel.momd/XRPackageModel 9.0.omo'
We couldn't boot your defined simulator due to an already booted simulator. We are limited to one simulator launched at a time.
Launching iPad Air (iOS 11.1)...`

I have tried:

- `watchman watch-del-all`, `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`, `npm start -- --reset-cache`
- cleaning the project
- restarting my computer

Some success was had with: `xcrun simctl list` and `xcrun simctl shutdown <booted simulator id>` in that the "simulator is already booted error disappeared" but the simulator still did not display.

This happens intermittently and sometimes resolves itself with (seemingly) no action on my end. This makes me think it may be a bug in xCode or react-native?  I'm at a loss at this point as to what to do to solve this issue.

Comment: well its not a react-native issue

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian could you tell me why you think that? My reasoning behind it is that it will often run just fine through xCode (vs the `react native run-ios` terminal command.)

Comment: Facing Same problem and it can get very frustrating at times.

Comment: @sarah55555 because its just a matter of how the simulator is being started. at most its react-native CLI calling the wrong things, but you can always just open the simulator itself.

Answer (score 6):

As stated in the issue, the problem is occurring due to an already running simulator in your environment. To fix this problem the following would be needed:

1. Identify the process that is running the simulator.

   > ps aux | grep launchd_sim | grep -v grep | awk '{print}'
2. Kill the particular running process

   > kill -9 {ProcessId}
3. Run your react-native simulator again.

   > react-native run-ios